# How to log out an user in php?

Tags: php, session, logout

Currently, in my php script, after an user logged in, i stored session_login = 1. But I have a problem. I have a habit in using firefox, multi-tab (i believe most people and all today web browsers app have multi-tab function). I closed the tab that has the session, but I didnt closed the browser. After few hours, I come back on the same page that require me to login, but it doesn't. It does not require me to login again(I think thats called "Session"). Is there anyway to logout the user if he close the tab instead close the browser??

I have 1 solution right now, time-idle kick out. But, I have very limited knowledge in date/time thing in php, so this would be the last option. I wanted to know, is there anything else i can do, beside using time-idle?

Comment: When using Amber's answer, you will be logged when you have *no activity* for one hour. The tab can be *still open* in the browser, but doing nothing there will automatically log you out *without any prompt*. Imagine a situation: you have a form open on the page for one hour, and after submit the data you find that you are logged out already. Or after having coffee break you are pressing a link and get kicked out. I think this will be a usability issue

Comment: Please test your project once again to see if I am right or not

Comment: Maybe you could see the same usability issue when using PHPMyAdmin when you got logged out unexpectedly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP has an easy way to set how long a session will last before it times out:

```
session_set_cookie_params(3600); // make it expire after 1 hour
```

Just pass it the number of seconds you want the session to last (in the example, 1 hour = 60 minutes = 3600 seconds).

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php

Comment: This method works for current project(solve my problem temporary). But next project i might need to use Richy C answer, because the user may stay on my site for more than 1 hour. Hard to choose best answer. Well, I will choose the best answer based on the "voted"

Comment: Your method will log the user out if there was no activity for one hour (even with the tab open). But the question was logging the user out when he closes a tab. PS

Comment: IMO, only AJAX requests repeating every N minutes can solve the task

Answer (score 2):

A session cookie is only cleared from the browser when the browser session is closed (i.e. when the browser is closed): hence the name. If you want the session to be cleared shortly after the tab is closed you could set a very short expiry time on the cookie (around 5 minutes) and store the same in the database. Then have a javascript function on the web page calling a file from your server every minute: this file then "refreshes" the cookie/database entry for the next five minutes. If they then leave your site for more than five minutes, then the session is invalidated.

You could also add a Javascript "onunload" function which detects if they have closed the webpage or gone to another page: you could add a hook on this to call a "destroycookie" function - however, you'll have to check that they haven't just gone to another page on your site and don't actually have two pages from your site open in two tabs.

Comment: This sounds cool. But unfortunately, I don't know JavaScript.

Comment: Oh ya, btw, you mentioned that "calling a file from your server every minute", if I have 1000 or more users on the same time logged in, thats means every minute my server need to response those 1000++ users, am I right? Will it slow down my server performance? Is there a better way?

Comment: A combination of http://www.quirksmode.org/js/xmlhttp.html and setInterval ( sendRequest('refresh.php'), 60000 ); to fetch the "refresh.php" every minute (6000 milliseconds) should do the job.

Comment: Yes, it could slow it down if you are having 1,000+ requests every minute: you could change the cookie timeout to 10 minutes and then refresh every 5 minutes or so to reduce any load.

Comment: 1)We can rely on browser cookie expiration only. In this case bbtang can fetch a 1-byte static file from a server using javascript every 5 minutes. This won't affect server load much and can be served by nginx. But we must test if all browsers will clean the cookies out after they are not used for 10 minutes!!! 2)We can check last user activity on the server using session mechanism or a database. In this case the server will get more loaded. But the second way is bulletproof

Answer (score 0):

I believe the option you are looking for is the setting for the session cookie expiration. I don't remember the PHP command for it, but you should be able to set the cookie to expire when the window closes.

Here is the PHP session documentation: https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php

Comment: Thanks for the link, I will definitely go and take a look

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use session_write_close()?

Comment: I am totally clueless about session_write_close(). I am a new php coder. I am gonna check this one out. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There's a comment on the PHP documentation for the session_destroy function that might be useful to you: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php#71889

Comment: I normally use the session_destroy only on logout page. Um, well, let me think about, I believe it might be useful in some way and probably could solved my problem.. Focus, focus, focus.. think, think, think....